# Vocabularies often appear on textbook but seldom used in real life

Tags: word-usage

천만에요 is a well-known Korean expression which almost always appear on Korean language textbooks. But that expression is rarely used in real life. (To be more precise, I think the frequency of that expression being used is very different in textbooks and real life.)

I tried to think about more such examples, but I couldn't think of any. What are such Korean vocabularies, namely often-used-in-textbooks-but-not-that-much-in-real-life?

Comment: This is not a direct answer but I want to introduce the following site https://hinative.com/ko/questions/2592159 (There is a similar question)

Comment: In the above link, 별말씀을 is not used frequently (별말씀을 = 천만에요 = you're welcome = response to "thank you")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I went to Korea got the impression that **그렇지만** was a reasonably general way of saying *but* and I guessed it would be a common word - but I rarely heard it when I was living there.

Also in textbooks I've seen, dialogues often have one person saying **오랜만이에요** - *long time no see* - but again I don't think I heard that expression often.

Let me know if I'm wrong on either of these!

Comment: Your answer made me think more. What do I say when I want to say "but" in Korean? In casual occasions I think I often use 근데. In formal writing I tend to use 하지만. Right, using 그렇지만 in spoken Korean sounds unnatural to me.

Answer (score 0):

Comment on topo morto's answer :

오랜만이야 is used often. I do not know exact situation of long time
no see. And Korean text book may use this word in the situation a
slightly different from real.

Usually, if we finish middle school, high school, or other and (at
least 5) 10 years are passed, then we say 오래간만이다, 오랜만이네,
오랜만이지, 오랜만이야 to friends (Almost, it is used in
schoolmates).

When I met an assistant of freshman's course at my age 25, he said
오랜만이다.

@ 조만간 또 보자. I want to see you again, less than a year.

@@ 간만이네. We met before, less than a year. Is this right ?